# Adding EKParticipants to an EKEvent

Tags: ios, objective-c, eventkit, ekevent

I'd like to programatically add a participant to an `EKEvent` on iOS.

`EKParticipant`'s class reference states "You do not create `EKParticipant` objects directly. Send attendees to an `EKEvent` object to get an array of `EKParticipant` objects.".

`EKEvent`'s class reference states that the 'attendees' member (`NSArray`) is "The attendees associated with the event, as an array of `EKParticipant` objects. (read-only)"

Answer (score 3):

Not possible. This is done deliberately by Apple so only the user can create or edit meetings' invitees. The only way is to display a `EKEventEditViewController` and let the user edit the list themselves.

You can delve into [private API](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EKCalendarItem.h), but you risk a 99% app store validation failure.

Comment: there an app available in App store [Tempo](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tempo-smart-calendar-free/id593819390) that modifies invitees without using `EventKitUI`.

Comment: @Afnan Tempo doesnot really write the invitees into system calendar.but calendar 5 do.